# Question about mean, max, and min function python

Tags: python

```
import statistics as stat
from statistics import mean
from random import seed, choice
from math import hypot
import random
from turtle import *
import statistics


seed(20190101)

def random_walk(n):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for i in range(n):
        step = random.choice(["N","S","E","W"])
        if step == 'N':
            y = y + 1
        elif step == "S":
            y = y - 1
        elif step == "E":
            x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x - 1
    return (x,y)

for i in range(100):
    walk = random_walk(50)
    y = abs(walk[0]) + abs(walk[1])
    x = statistics.mean(y)

print(x)
```

please ignore the unused modules

So I am trying to get the mean of the numbrs from the function random_walk, but I am having a couple of issues.

First, I am supposed to be starting the program on a 0,0 grid. I am trying to find the mean of the trials for 100 steps and 50 different styles from the seed provided. But it isn't working correctly, and I have no idea why..

Comment: You're running your main loop 100 times, but you're discarding the results of every iteration but the last.  All you're doing it printing `statistics.mean(y)` for the final value of `y` (which I think will give you an error since `y` is not an iterable).  You need to save the values in a list, then call `mean` once with the list as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the `mean` for each value returned from `random_walk()` inside the loop, over-ridding the previous value. Change the loop to:

```
all_steps = []
for i in range(100):
    walk = random_walk(50)
    all_steps.append(abs(walk[0]) + abs(walk[1]))
steps_mean = statistics.mean(all_steps) #Only after the loop
print(steps_mean)
```